# How Decorator Pattern Follows Composition

Tags: java

I read in HeadFirst DesginPattern book that decorator pattern uses composition relation to provide additional functionality to an object dynamically. But in the following code I found the aggregation relation instead of composition.

As far I know the difference between the composition and aggregation is:

**Aggregation :** Life or existence of the aggregated objects are independent of each                  other, But one object is playing the role of Owner of the other object.

**Composition :** Life or existence of the composite object is dependent on the existence of container object, Existence of composite object is not meaningful without its container object.

```
public abstract class Girl {

    String description = "no particular";

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }
}

public class AmericanGirl extends Girl {

    public AmericanGirl(){
        description = "+American";
    }
}

public class EuropeanGirl extends Girl {

    public EuropeanGirl() {
        description = "+European";
    }
}

public abstract class GirlDecorator extends Girl {

    public abstract String getDescription();
}

public class Science extends GirlDecorator {

    private Girl girl;

    public Science(Girl g) {
        girl = g;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return girl.getDescription() + "+Like Science";
    }

    public void caltulateStuff() {
        System.out.println("scientific calculation!");
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Girl g1 = new AmericanGirl();
        System.out.println(g1.getDescription()); 
        Science g2 = new Science(g1);
        System.out.println(g2.getDescription());        
    }
}
```

Can someone point out/explain how the above code follows composition?

Comment: A good explanation: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/61527

Comment: ..maybe "HeadFirst DesginPattern book" is not as strict (as you) with its definition. (since many people just loosely use both terms as synonym for a (what-ever) "1 to N relationship")

Comment: I know this old but it comes up top in google searches.. It looks from your example as if Science cannot exist without a Girl object to decorate and functionally it serves no purpose without it. Is this not composition? I always think of human and heart as composition, student and school as aggregation.. very basic but useful in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The similarities between *`aggregation`* and *`composition`* make them often used as synonyms. IMO if you don't have a reason to make the distinction, it isn't worth the time debating on which it actually is. If you do have a reason, you probably already know which it falls under.

They are close enough in concepts that they are how you treat them. If you use the relationship as a single unit then it is a *`composition`*. If you interact with them independently of one another then it is an *`aggregation`*.

The major detail is in why it matters. The main need for a distinction between the two that I can think of is garbage collection. In an *`aggregation`* properties of the container may still be meaningful outside of their container context. In a *`composition`* properties of the container should be destroyed with the container.

When one observes the value of existence of an object inverse to the definition, I believe it can be expressed as both. In some circumstances you may wish to destroy only the container and retain the contents (*`aggregation`*). However, without it's delegate it is meaningless. This defines somewhat of an *`inverse composition`*. You would never want to destroy the child and retain the decorator.

Although `Science` is in fact a concrete `Girl`, the implementation of `Science.getDescription` overrides the base implementation to delegate the request to a concrete `Girl`. This implementation detail makes the `Science` girl meaningless without being initialized with a valid `Girl` implementation.

If the existence by itself is meaningless, then it usually isn't an *`aggregation`* and is probably instead a *`composition`*.

As an aside, decorators are more clearly expressed by implementing an interface rather than inheriting a base class. Adhering to the single responsibility principal you can then be certain that the decorator is not an implementation of the subject.